# API to get Rider History with Cost

Tags: uber-api

I can't seem to find Uber API that will give me the details of the rider's past trips, specifically Date, Time and Costs.

They provide: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/history-get however doesn't give the Cost which is the most important piece of information for my app.

Anyone know if that is possible to get ? Thanks!

Comment: Hi-- price is intentionally excluded from that endpoint. What you are looking for is not possible through the rider API unless the rider takes all the trips through your app and you use the /receipt endpoint.

Comment: The rider has taken all the trips from the app - user I'm creating this for. The price data is still not available, when and how will that be made available to developers like myself?

Comment: If the user has taken all the trips from your app (which you have request & request_receipt scopes for) than you would call the receipt endpoint.

Comment: can you provide details with perhaps an example as answer ?

Comment: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-request_id-get   is the request endpoint for an individual trip which includes fare amounts. As mentioned though this is only applicable if the user took a ride through your app where you called the request endpoint. From how you are responding to my replies, that does not seem likely here.